# AWS CDK how to embed custom java script in request template of gateway lambda Integration

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

From the AWS console we can set java script in integration request template mapping. the same can not be set through AWS CDK.

Template mapping from api gateway integration request allows to set application/json, with which we can also embed java script code as shown below, 
Similar way how to achieve in CDK

```
{"action": "hello",
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
"endPoints": [
#foreach($elem in $inputRoot.endPoints)
    {
    #set($headers = $elem.headers)
    #if($headers != "")
        "headers": "$elem.headers",
    #end
    "uri": "$elem.uri",
    "info": "$elem.info"
    }
 #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
 #end
 ]}
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be handled through programming i am withdrawing this issue. we can pass it as string like

```
"""
{"action": "hello",
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
"endPoints": [
#foreach($elem in $inputRoot.endPoints)
    {
    #set($headers = $elem.headers)
    #if($headers != "")
        "headers": "$elem.headers",
    #end
    "uri": "$elem.uri",
    "info": "$elem.info"
    }
 #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
 #end
 ]}
"""
```